# Django db not printing in html table

Tags: html, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I'm currently new to studying Django for cour Software Engineering class. Our teacher gave us an activity to apply CRUD using Django. However, everytime I click submit, nothing appears in my html table. Here's my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.

class ClassList(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length = 9, blank = False)
    course = models. CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('server_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import ClassList

class ListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClassList
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'id_number', 'course',)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import ListForm
from .models import ClassList

admin.site.register(ClassList)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.input_student, name='input_student'),
    url(r'^list/', views.student_list, name='student_list'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import ClassList
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import ListForm

def input_student(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            lists = form.save(commit=False)
            lists.published_date = timezone.now()
            lists.is_active = True
            lists.save()

            return redirect('student_list')
    else:
        form = ListForm()
    return render(request, 'crud_app/form.html', {'form': form})

def student_list(request):
    lists = ClassList.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'crud_app/list.html', {'lists': lists})

def edit(request, pk):
    lists = get_object_or_404(ClassList, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListForm(request.POST, instance=lists)
        if form.is_valid():
            lists.form.save(commit=False)
            lists.published_date=timezone.now()
            lists.save()
            return redirect('student_list')
    else:
        form = ListForm(instance=lists)
    return render(request, {'form': form})

def reg_delete(request, pk):
    lists = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=pk)
    lists.is_active = False
    lists.save()
    return redirect('list')
```

form.html

```
   {% extends "crud_app/home.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="POST" class="list-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="add-button">Add Student</button>
        <button a href = "{% url "student_list" %}">View List</a></button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

list.html

```
{% extends "crud_app/home.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>ID Number</th>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for lists in object_list %}
                {% if lists.is_active == True %} 
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ lists.last_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ lists.first_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ lists.id_number }}</td>
                        <td>{{ lists.course }}</td>
                        <td><a href="">Edit</a></td> 
                        <td><a href="">Delete</a></td> -->
                    </tr>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

{% endblock content %}
```

any help would be deeply appreciated. thanks.

Comment: can show the views.py code?

Comment: views would be helpful, I hardly ever use django forms, do you need to tell it to also work with your bool value?

Comment: Have ClassList objects in database saved? if yes, how many?

Comment: @PauloPessoa, I'm not really sure. But eveyrtime I input something, it appears in localhost:8000/admin. But it doesn't  appear in my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    return render(request, 'crud_app/list.html', {'lists': lists})
```

You are pass 'lists' to the context, not 'object_list'.

Change the key to **object_list**, will works.

```
    return render(request, 'crud_app/list.html', {'object_list': lists})
```

**Or** Change the for in list.html to this:

```
{% for list in lists %}
    {% if list.is_active == True %} 
        <tr>
            <td>{{ list.last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ list.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ list.id_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ list.course }}</td>
            <td><a href="">Edit</a></td> 
            <td><a href="">Delete</a></td> -->
         </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @user3385560 Appreciate if mark that is the answer. thanks.